# Android get context in database

Tags: android, database, android-context

I have one database and I've created a `Database` class that has a `private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` to help me manage my database.

This database is access from four different activities.

I have this `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` that it's what creates my database tables and adds values to those tables. Since the program only enter here the first time the user runs the app, I want to create a `ProgressDialog`.

This is what I have:

```
Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    ProgressDialog progresso = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Info", "Loading DB" );
    // Code to create the tables and add the values
    progress.dismiss();
}
```

Got 2 questions.

First:

Since this can be accessed from 4 different activities how can I get the context?
Making:

```
Context context = getAplicationContext();
```

Second:

Why can't I use strings from strings.xml?
I can't make this:

```
ProgressDialog progresso = ProgressDialog.show(context, getString(R.string.driProgressTitle), getString(R.string.driProgressMessage) );
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class Database {
    ProgressDialog progresso;
    private DbHelper DBHelper;
    private final Context Context;
    private SQLiteDatabase BaseDados;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, BD_NAME, null, BD_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // Whanted to show here the progress dialog
        new loadDB().execute();

        // Creates the table and adds the values

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVesion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MYTABLE");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public Database(Context c) {
        Context = c;
    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException {
        DBHelper = new DbHelper(Context);
        BaseDados = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getData(int tipo, long groupId, String query[]) {
        // Performs the querys to my database
    }
    return null;
}

    public class loadDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            progresso = ProgressDialog.show(Context, Context.getString(R.string.ProgressTitle), Context.getString(R.string.ProgressMessage) );
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            progresso.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code I'm getting this error `No enclosing instance of type Database is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Database (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Database).` in `new loadDB().execute();`.

Comment: No, you can not touch anything related to GUI inside of `doInBackground()` method. Override `onPreExecute()`  and there call `ProgressDialog.show()` .

Comment: @wingman Ok. Done that. But were do I call `new loadDB().execute();`?

Comment: any where outside of `loadDB`, basically in `onStart()` of your activity.

Comment: @wingman doing new loadDB().execute(); in the `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` of my `Database class it gives this error: `No enclosing instance of type Database is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Database (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Database).` Doing `new loadDB().execute();` in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of my main class/activity it gives the error: `loadDB cannot be resolved to a type`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8):

Don't you have access to the Context from the constructor?

```
SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)

SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
```

**EDIT:**

Your code:

```
public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, BD_NAME, null, BD_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

You have access to the context at this point.. can you just do something like add a field called context then do this:

```
Context context;
public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, BD_NAME, null, BD_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Now, you have access to the context anywhere in the class? Assuming that the constructor is called before onCreate.

Comment: My constructor is not like that. Please see my updated question

Comment: Thanks. Now the problem is on `new loadDB().execute();`. doing `new loadDB().execute();` in the `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` of my `Database` class it gives this error: `No enclosing instance of type Database is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Database (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Database).` Doing `new loadDB().execute();` in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of my main class/activity it gives the error: `loadDB cannot be resolved to a type`.

Comment: Your inner class needs a reference to the outer class. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633585/strange-syntax-for-instantiating-an-inner-class

Comment: @cskoalo Thanks. It's working ok but now it does not show the `ProgressDialog` Pasted here the code if you have the time http://pastebin.com/M5pJc6fy

Answer (score 1):

The `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)` method only gets called the first time you make a call to `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase` (i.e. the first time it is opened), not when the app is first run (of course you could first this to happen by simply opening the database the closing it).

I'm not sure giving it the Application context will work since the progressDialog will need to be displayed in the currently running Activity.

Instead of trying to display progress bars for precisely when the database is first accessed, have your current Activity display one any time it access the database itself. That way the first access to the database is masked by regular access to it.

If you don't want to display progress bars for all DB access, then again you can just open and close the database and have your Activity display a progress bar before you open it, and remove the progress bar when you close it (not doing anything with the database except let `onCreate()` run).

Unless your database structures are really big, you probably won't even see the progress bar. It doesn't take very long to create the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use Loader for reading data from DB. Don't clutter background classes with UI stuff

```
onCreateLoader(.. 
   //you can start progress

onLoadFinished(..
   // you can stop it
```

Also you read data from background thread which is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You're unable to access the context of the application, as SQLiteOpenHelper does not have contain these methods (unlike Activity)

My advice to you is to use the DbHelper class to set up the database and to manage any sql transactions. Have it's constructor take a context object, then create instances of it within a class which extends Activity, passing the context through to the constructor.

It would also be good practice to have a data access object class sitting inbetween the activity and the sqlliteOpenHelper, to manage opening, closing and issuing transactions too your database object

Comment: Is you may be able to guess, the application Is expecting an instance of the database to execute against, are you declaring an instance of the database in your calling activity? Then calling loaddb() against that?

Comment: sorry but didn't understand. I should do something like `Database db= new Database(this); new loadDB().execute(); db.open();` in the activity that calls the database?

Comment: Try opening the database before executing

Answer (score 0):

To show user progress, you will have to run your work in a separate thread, otherwise GUI will just freeze until the database work is completed and user may get the *"Activity not responding, force close"* message.

Use `Application` class to store a global flag about if database has been created or not.

Any starting activity checks this flag, if database has not been initialized, it creates an `AsyncTask` , passes on db and its own context in constructor. `AsyncTask` will have three methods:

1. onPreExecute : show your dialog here. Make dialog non cancel able so user can't skip it.
2. doInBackground : database building code here. (call the Database helper class methods)
3. onPostExecute : dismiss the dialog. Now user can interact with the Activity.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion but got errors. Please see my uptaded question