# Confusion with generics, interfaces, and extending

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable

So I'm trying to write a program for a generic linked list and skip list. I also wanted to use an interface and superclass while I'm at it, for future use, but I can't seem to figure out how to make everything work together with all the generic types.

This is the basic idea of what I have right now:

My list ADT and node class that everything will extend off of:

```
public class Node<K extends Comparable<K>> {
    K key;
    Object data;
    ...
}

public interface List<T> {
    public void insert(T value);
    public void delete(T value);
}
```

And for an example of a linked list:

```
public class LList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements List<LLNode<T>>
public class LLNode<K extends Comparable<K>> extends Node<K>
```

Am I doing this right?

Edit: More specifically, I am running into issues when I try to make very basic instances of this class, such as ...

```
List<String> linkedList = new LList<String>();
List[] lists = {linkedList};
sets[0].insert("cookie");
```

This gives me a compiler error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to project.LLNode

Comment: What makes you think it isn't correct? Do you have a compiler error or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633585/strange-syntax-for-instantiating-an-inner-class

Comment: I'll take a look at that thread. I updated with my compiler error.

Comment: As written here, `LList<String>` isn't assignable to `List<String>`, but `List<LLNode<String>>`, so the insert call expects an `LLNode` instead of a string.

Comment: How can I restructure this so that LList<String> works?

Comment: `new List<String>()`? But `List` is an interface, it cannot be instantiated. Shouldn't that be `LList`?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I thought in three options:

**First**, will work with `List<String>`:

```
    public class LList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements List<T>
    {
        @Override
        public void insert(T value)
        ...
    }
```

this way no more `Node` will be needed.

**OR**, your **second** option: you can keep the way you implemented and use `List<LLNode<String>>`

**OR**, **finally** if you need both use `Node` and this `List<String>` that I suppose that's your need (it wasn't clear from de question), and use `Node` s just internally using the first option, if it's not possible, please be clearer on your needs and I'll try to help you.

Regards.