# How creation an instance of inner class works?

Tags: java

When I create an instance of inner class, I use this code.

```
OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass();
OuterClass.InnerClass inerClass = outerClass.new InnerClass();
```

But I don't understand how `outerClass.new InnerClass()` works, why we use `.new` it like new its inner class, I understand it is not, but I do not understand the syntax.

Comment: This may help [Strange syntax for instantiating an inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633585/strange-syntax-for-instantiating-an-inner-class)

Comment: An instance of an inner class has an implicit reference to its owner class instance. If you just used `new OuterClass.InnerClass()`, how could the compiler know which outer class instance to pass to the inner class instance? So the Java designers had to decide on a syntax allowing to specify the outer class instance when newing the inner class, and that's the syntax they chose. You very, very rarely use that syntax in practice, because the inner instance is usually created from a method/constructor of the outer class.

Comment: Check this oracle docs, you will get clear concepts on this. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *inner class* is POJO. So, when you look in the target directory, you see 2 (two) class files.
Therefore to create an instance of the *inner class* you use new.

```
OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass();  // create instance
OuterClass.InnerClass inerClass = outerClass.new InnerClass();  // innerClass has `this` to outerClass instance
```

It means that `InnerClass` is not a static (i.e. has `this` reference to an object of `OuterClass`) and instance of `OuterClass` should be created prior to it.

```
OuterClass.InnerClass inerClass = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
```

It means that `InnerClass` is a static (i.e. has not `this` reference to an object of `Outerlass`) and it means, this is absolutely the same (from the JVM perspective) like two separate files with `class OuterClass` and `class InnterClass`.